# concurrency issues in case of incorrect final variable initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, final

In the book the Art of Multiprocessor programming On page 64, Chapter 3- Concurrent Objects there is an example below

```
Public class EventListener {

final int x;

public EventListener(EventSource source){

eventSource.registerListener(source);

}

public onEvent(Event e){
..//handle the event

}

}
```

As per the book above class is incorrect. And it says following text "This code may appear safe, since registration is the last step in the constructor, but it is incorrect, because if another  thread calls the method onEvent() method before constructor finishes,then the onEvent() methos is not guaranteed to see a correct value for x"

The simulation code can be

```
public class TestClass {
    private EventListener listener2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass f1 = new TestClass();
        listenerThread lThread = f1.new listenerThread();
        initializerThread iThread = f1.new initializerThread();
        lThread.start();
        iThread.start();
    }

    class listenerThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if(listener2!=null){
                    listener2.onEvent(new Event("hello"));
                }
            }

        }
    }

    class initializerThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (listener2 == null) {
                    listener2 = new EventListener();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My doubt is as per Java Language specification  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5 the result of new EventListener() will not
be available until the constructor creation completes which means variable x will get initialized before variable listener2 is assigned a value other than null. 
Then there is no way listenerThread can see different value for x. Is there any other way to reproduce the issue the author mentions here..i.e. another thread seeing 
different value for x.

Comment: I guess , not possible to precisely answer unless you show where and how instance variable `final int x` being used in your `EventListener` class.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer is in this page
https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html